# Is there a way to get unique rows for same value

Tags: php, mysql, database

Hello and sorry if this questions isn't good formatted, here's my problem: 
for simplicity let's say i have a table with products

```
-----------------------
| id|  age |price|name| 
----------------------|
| 0 | 0   |  50  | x  |
| 1 | 1   |  51  | x  |
| 2 | 2   |  52  | x  |
| 3 | 3   |  53  | x  |
| 4 | 4   |  54  | x  |
| 5 | 5   |  55  | x  |
| 6 | 6   |  56  | x  |
| 7 | 7   |  57  | x  |
| 8 | 8   |  58  | x  |
-----------------------
```

I want to get the price for all products of age 0 and 1 with

```
select price from products where name='x' and(age=0 or age=1)
```

and it works returning two rows but when the age is the same logically it returns one row and that's my problem how to get it to return again all the rows i want or if something other is wrong with my logic, thank you in advance

Comment: `select * from products where name='x' and(age=0 or age=1) `?

Comment: this will print only one row as i explain in my question it should return only one row  @Maurice

Comment: Even if the age was the same, ( e.g. change age 0 to age 1, so two `1`s ) that query would still return 2 rows.

Comment: Please include your expected output.  For two rows, how do you want to report a single price?  Using the average, or something else?

Comment: `select * from products where name='x' and age in (0, 1)` is working for me.

Comment: @Maurice and it's working for me two but i want to return two rows even if the have the same age eg ```select * from products where name='x' and age in (0, 0)``` which returns one rwo

Comment: @AntoniosLampros what? A query will return you the results based on the conditions. If you only want to return name x and age 0 you will get only one row. Just remove the where condition and you get all.

Comment: @Maurice let me explain my problem better because i think that maybe my fault lies elsewhere the products are insurance prices and i query from a php page the price for a product base on customer age customer can select a product for his wife and if his wife has the same age based on my query ill get only on product and i want two so maybe my logic for building the query is wrong?

Comment: @Maurice or maybe i should do two queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to build a derived table of the ages that you want to query against and then `JOIN` that to the `products` table. Note that you need to use `UNION ALL` in the derived table to maintain duplicates. Additional values can be searched by adding another `UNION ALL SELECT n` to the derived table for each value:

```
SELECT p.price
FROM (SELECT 0 AS age
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 0) ages
JOIN products p ON p.age = ages.age
WHERE p.name = 'x'
```

Output:

```
price
50
50
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pBpTiHn9rgm8rAioHCW4V7/0)